# WINAPI CreateFile with FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE not work on the shared folder

Tags: windows, visual-c++, smb

CreateFile with FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE to open a file on a shared folder.

Then Call ReplaceFile to replace this file.

ReplaceFile fail with ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION.

After some dig, I found is rename file operation inside ReplaceFile failed with ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION.

Why FILE_SHARE_DELETE didn't work on the shared folder?

Can I solve this ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION problem?

Comment: It is pretty easy to use ReplaceFile() incorrectly, programmers tend to be mystified about the importance of the 3rd argument.  We can't see it.

Comment: Are you sure this has anything to do with SMB? Did you try to replicate the problem with a local folder accessed directly (i.e. no UNC path)? Are you certain that all opens for *both* `lpReplacedFileName` and `lpReplacementFileName` share delete access? The replacement file has to be renamed to the replaced filename, which requires delete access on both files.

Comment: @eryksun  I'm pretty sure. I only open the lpReplacedFileName. And process monitor logs show ReplaceFile failed when renaming the lpReplacedFileName.

Comment: After a few more tests, I start to think it's Microsoft Office's bug. Actually, the problem I have is Microsoft Office call ReplaceFile when my program opens a .ppt file. I test two environment now. On win7 x86 with office 2007 problem occurs. On win10 with office 2016 the problem not exist.